# How can I translate a query from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to migrate a simple stored procedure from SQL Server to Oracle.

I have already tried a few online converters but with no success, such as the Scratch editor. Can anyone help?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] @DOCID INT 
AS 
    DECLARE @TXT VARCHAR(500); 

    SET @TXT= Concat ('Test ', (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), d5, 2) 
                                FROM   data6 
                                WHERE  id = @DOCID), ',', 'and ', 
              Char(10) + Char(13), (SELECT d2 
                                   FROM data6 
                                   WHERE id = @DOCID))
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code does.  You should only be porting code when you understand what it is doing.

Comment: yes I'm understanding what the code does in tsql, but I can't translate it in Oracle..
it declares a variable  in which takes a conversion of numerical  and text data and it returns that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand that syntax, but it seems this is a simple SELECT statement:

```
create or replace procedure test(doc_id number)
as
  l_text varchar(500);
begin
  select 'Test'||to_char(d5,'yy.mm.dd')||chr(10)||chr(13)||d2
    into l_text
  from data6
  where id = doc_id;
end;
```

Not sure what the `convert()` function does, I think the `2` means that you are trying to format a date.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=367ac76771dcc21d51b5407c43d55d14)

Comment: Yes the number 2 is a format type.. i tried this but it returns me 'Syntax error:partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams)...how can i solve this?

Comment: @helloandroiddevelopers: sorry, the `declare` was wrong.

Comment: it returns me the ORA-01403 error although when i run the same in a simple query everything is fine....